# how to render or embed ArangoDB's graph in my web application that hosted in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graph, arangodb

Im running ArangoDB in AWS server i able to generate the graph in the ArangoDB web interface. But one of my use case is that, im required to display/render/embed the graph generated by the ArangoDB in my frontend web application that hosted using vue js. how can i achieve this use case? am i required to find a third party graph explorer tool to do so?
here's the example response that i get from ArangoDB AQL:

```js
[
  {
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "684201",
        "_id": "dev_user/684201",
        "_rev": "_e6sXZR----",
        "account_flags": [],
        "email": "vava@g2g.com",
        "full_name": "Loh Wei Min"
      },
      {
        "_key": "103.3.21.54",
        "_id": "ip_address/103.3.21.54",
        "_rev": "_e6sWLaq---"
      }
    ],
    "edges": [
      {
        "_key": "276292",
        "_id": "user_relation_ips/276292",
        "_from": "dev_user/684201",
        "_to": "ip_address/103.3.21.54",
        "_rev": "_e6sXZou---"
      }
    ],
    "weights": [
      0,
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "684201",
        "_id": "dev_user/684201",
        "_rev": "_e6sXZR----",
        "account_flags": [],
        "email": "vava@g2g.com",
        "full_name": "Loh Wei Min"
      },
      {
        "_key": "202.184.222.30",
        "_id": "ip_address/202.184.222.30",
        "_rev": "_e6sV2ES---"
      }
    ],
    "edges": [
      {
        "_key": "276289",
        "_id": "user_relation_ips/276289",
        "_from": "dev_user/684201",
        "_to": "ip_address/202.184.222.30",
        "_rev": "_e6sXZmO---"
      }
    ],
    "weights": [
      0,
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "684201",
        "_id": "dev_user/684201",
        "_rev": "_e6sXZR----",
        "account_flags": [],
        "email": "vava@g2g.com",
        "full_name": "Loh Wei Min"
      },
      {
        "_key": "211.24.73.181",
        "_id": "ip_address/211.24.73.181",
        "_rev": "_e6sV0vS---"
      }
    ],
    "edges": [
      {
        "_key": "276286",
        "_id": "user_relation_ips/276286",
        "_from": "dev_user/684201",
        "_to": "ip_address/211.24.73.181",
        "_rev": "_e6sXZl----"
      }
    ],
    "weights": [
      0,
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "684201",
        "_id": "dev_user/684201",
        "_rev": "_e6sXZR----",
        "account_flags": [],
        "email": "vava@g2g.com",
        "full_name": "Loh Wei Min"
      },
      {
        "_key": "211.24.73.170",
        "_id": "ip_address/211.24.73.170",
        "_rev": "_e6sUDn2---"
      }
    ],
    "edges": [
      {
        "_key": "276283",
        "_id": "user_relation_ips/276283",
        "_from": "dev_user/684201",
        "_to": "ip_address/211.24.73.170",
        "_rev": "_e6sXZie---"
      }
    ],
    "weights": [
      0,
      1
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end we switched from ArangoDB to AWS Neptune for data storing purpose and render the graph in frontend using vis.js

Comment: Mark your answer as the solution, please.